# How to fetch distinct dates from a CSV file and iterate a query for deletion on Azure DataFactory Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to import paycheck data from a csv file which is located at Azure BLOB Storage into Azure Database on ADF. Since paycheck schedules are fixed if batch of `PaycheckDate` was already on a table, existing data of a given `PaycheckDate` should be cleaned up before importing and (new) entries in the file are expected to be imported for a given `PaycheckDate`. (There is no unique identifiers on a file to pick up a particular entry)

For a file,
there is a CSV file, for example, `Paycheck_202402.csv` on `PaycheckContainer` of BLOB Storage, and here is a schema and data. (About 28K rows in a file)

```
CompanyId,EmployeeId,PaycheckDate,Amount,Description
100,e1234,2024-02-09,150.5,Overtime
100,e1234,2024-02-09,1500.0,Salary
100,e1234,2024-02-23,305.25,Overtime
100,e1234,2024-02-23,1500.0,Salary
200,e2222,2024-02-09,50.5,Tip
200,e2222,2024-02-09,500.0,Salary
400,e5555,2024-02-15,1000,Compensate
400,e5555,2024-02-23,1500.0,Salary
```

For target a table called as `factPaychecks`, here is a simple schema

```
CompanyId INT,
EmployeeId VARCHAR,
PaycheckDate DATE,
Amount DOUBLE(10,2),
Description VARCHAR
```

What I'd like to do is

- to extract unique PaycheckDates from a file into an array, so the expected result is `arrCheckDates` = [2024-02-09, 2024-02-15, 2024-02-23].
- to pass `arrCheckDates` to For-Each activity,
- and then iterate a DELETE query against `factPaychecks` by a given `PaycheckDate`

```
DELETE FROM `factPaychecks` WHERE [PaycheckDate] = $PaycheckDate
```

- to import entries in a file to `factPaychecks`

I tried

1. DataFlow(`DFImportPCK`) for extracting PaycheckDates and sink to Cache

1.1. `((Source))` from CSV

1.2. `((Aggregate))` [Group by] `PaycheckDate` with [Aggregates] NumOfRows(PaycheckDate)

1.3. `((Select))` `PaycheckDate` only - checked the result is DATE type

1.4. ``` ((Sink))`` [Type] as ``` Cache`, [Options] checked Write to activity output, [Key column] List of columns (no columns are assigned) --> Inspect/Data Preview : DATE type
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7Atu.png

2. Assign the returned value to an array type variable `varArrPaycheckDates` on a pipeline(`PLImportPCK`)

```
varArrPaycheckDates = @activity('DFImportPCK').output.runStatus.output.Sink2Cache.value
```

There are couple of issues I have

1. In DataFlow(`DFImportPCK`), I could see only 1 entry `2024-02-09` at `((Aggregate))`

```
`PaycheckDate` 2024-02-09 `NumOfRows` 1000
```

It's same as subsequent steps even `((Sink))` I could see `2024-02-09` only.
But it must be 3 elements like above [2024-02-09, 2024-02-15, 2024-02-23]
2. DataFlow(`DFImportPCK`) returns a (LONG)INTEGER value `1688688000000` not `2024-02-09` DATE type.

Could you guide me how I can achieve my goal or point me out what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DataFlow(`DFImportPCK`) returns a (LONG)INTEGER value  `1688688000000`  not  `2024-02-09`  DATE type.

The issue is with the date type First you need to cast it as string type as below:

[image]

Then in DataFlow setting **set logging level none and uncheck First Row Only**.

[image]

then in dataflow Output you can see array of `PaycheckDate`.

[image]

then Add for each loop to iterate on this array. with expreassion

```
@activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.Sink1.value
```

[image]

Under foreach activity take append variable with expression `@item().PaycheckDate`
to store all values in single array.

[image]

After execution of for each append variable will look like this :

[image]